# Am I implementing the tableviewdatasource correctly to get downloaded data to show?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift5

I am developing a small app to connect to my site, download data via a PHP web service, and display it in a table view. To get started I was following a tutorial over on Medium by Jose Ortiz Costa ([Article on Medium](https://medium.com/@joseortizcosta/connecting-ios-app-to-mysql-database-with-swift-5-using-protocol-delegation-and-mvc-architectural-259dc32fcc4b)).

I tweaked his project and got it running to verify the Web service was working and able to get the data. Once I got that working, I started a new project and tried to pull in some of the code that I needed to do the networking and tried to get it to display in a tableview in the same scene instead of a popup scene like Jose's project.

This is where I am running into some issues, as I'm still rather new to the swift programming language (started a Udemy course and have been picking things up from that) getting it to display in the table view. I can see that the request is still being sent/received, but I cannot get it to appear in the table view (either using my custom XIB or a programmatically created cell). I thought I understood how the code was broken down, and even tried to convert it from a UITableViewController to a UITableviewDataSource via an extension of the Viewcontroller.

At this point, I'm pretty stumped and will continue to inspect the code and tweak what I think might be the root cause. Any pointers on how to fix would be really appreciated!

[Main Storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91vq5.png)

**Struct for decoding my data / Lead class:**

```
import Foundation

struct Lead: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var program: String
    var stage: String
    var lastAction: String
}

class LeadModel {

weak var delegate: Downloadable?
let networkModel = Network()

func downloadLeads(parameters: [String: Any], url: String) {
    
    let request = networkModel.request(parameters: parameters, url: url)
    
    networkModel.response(request: request) { (data) in
        let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Lead]?.self, from: data) as [Lead]?
        self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: model! as [Lead])
    }
  }
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class LeadViewController: UIViewController {

// Buttons
@IBOutlet weak var newButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var firstContactButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondContactButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var leadTable: UITableView!
let model = LeadModel()
var models: [Lead]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Make Buttons rounded
    newButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    firstContactButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    secondContactButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    
    //Delegate
    model.delegate = self
}
    
    //Send request to web service based off Buttons Name
    @IBAction func findLeads(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let new = sender.titleLabel?.text
        let param = ["stage": new!]
        
        print ("findLead hit")
        model.downloadLeads(parameters: param, url: URLServices.leads)
    }

}

extension LeadViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    print ("number of sections hit")
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    guard let _ = self.models else {
        return 0
    }
    print ("tableView 1 hit")
    return self.models!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Create an object from LeadCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leadID", for: indexPath) as! LeadCell
    
    // Lead selection
    cell.leadName.text = self.models![indexPath.row].name
    cell.actionName.text = self.models![indexPath.row].lastAction
    cell.stageName.text = self.models![indexPath.row].stage
    cell.progName.text = self.models![indexPath.row].program
    
    print ("tableView 2 hit")
    
    // Return the configured cell
    return cell
  }
}

extension LeadViewController: Downloadable {

func didReceiveData(data: Any) {
    
    //Assign the data and refresh the table's data
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.models = data as? [Lead]
        self.leadTable.reloadData()
        
        print ("LeadViewController Downloadable Hit")
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

So with a little searching around (okay...A LOT of searching around), I finally found a piece that said I had to set the class as the datasource.

```
leadTable.dataSource = self
```

So that ended up working (well after I added a prototype cell with the identifier used in my code). I have a custom XIB that isn't working right now and that's my next tackle point.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please *do not post screenshots* of your code - it is difficult to read. Paste the code in your question, properly formatted. See also [ask].

Comment: as @Alexander Gaidukov said, you need to become the `delegate` of your model object so you can be notified once the request is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load the data, but don't use it. First, add the following statement to the end of the `viewDidLoad` method

```
model.delegate = self
```

Then add the following `LeadViewController` extension

```
extension LeadViewController: Downloadable {
    func dicReceiveData(data: [Lead]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.models = data
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

And a couple of suggestions:
It is not a good practice to use the button title as a network request parameter:

```
let new = sender.titleLabel?.text
let param = ["stage": new!]
```

It is better to separate UI and logic. You can use the `tag` attribute for buttons (you can configure it in the storyboard or programmatically) to check what button is tapped.

You also have several unnecessary type casts in the `LeadModel` class. You can change

```
let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Lead]?.self, from: data) as [Lead]?
self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: model! as [Lead])
```

to

```
do {
    let model = try JSONDecoder().decode([Lead].self, from: data)
    self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: model)
}
catch {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I made the changes you mentioned for the logic, however it still doesn't show up in the table view. I dropped some print statements in to show when the functions were hit and it seems to not hit the last tableview function to return the cell. Also, should I change the implementation of Downloadable, because it was set to any and then I got an error saying it didn't conform to Downloadable

Comment: So I've spent the past two days trying to figure out why it doesn't seem to be hitting the functions @Alexander  

Do you know why it might not be displaying?

Comment: @Omega636 it is hard to say from the code you provided. If you provide the link to your project on GitHub I can have a look.